# Preventing a Print expression from generating a new cell each time it executed

Tags: front-end, button

In reference to the following code:

```
Button["Start", Print[Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 1}]]]
```

When I click on the button the first time, I get a plot of $y = x^3$, perfect. When I click "Start" a second time, however, I find the new plot does not over-write the first, but appears below it, and I do not like that. How can I make the second plot overwrite the previous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way, based on the self-delete example in the documentation for [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html#1958852130):

```
Button["Start", SelectionMove[ButtonNotebook[], All, GeneratedCell]; 
 NotebookDelete[ButtonNotebook[]]; Print[Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 1}]]]
```