# How to prevent overwriting the latest output

Tags: front-end, cells

Suppose I have a long notebook with three parts:

```
Remove["Global`*"];

(*global settings*)
$globalvariable[]=1;

(*main functions*)
foo[]:=Print@$globalvariable[];

(*collecting the results*)
foo[]
```

Each time using this notebook, I just change the global settings and then `Evaluate Notebook`. The problem is that the `Output[]` in the third part will be overwritten, and to prevent this behaviour I need to add a new line by hand between `foo[]` and `Output[]`.

Is there a method of preventing overwriting the output only for `foo[]` without modifying any behaviour of `foo[]`?

I tried wrapping `foo[]` with `Button`

```
Button["test",foo[]]
```

as in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91986/) but failed:

- when `foo[]` is complicated containing `Print`, `Message`, `Timing`, etc, `Button["test",foo[]]`'s result is different from `foo[]`;
- when `Button["test",foo[]]` is re-evaluated, the results generated by the button will be cleared.

I think there should be more direct approach but am not familiar with the front-end issues.

---

### update 1

The situation is that when I am developing some package, this notebook serves as a pre-package before integrating the codes into `*.wl`. I need to modify the global settings and main functions according to the outputs.

I think the current comments and answers are suitable for the final stable version of the codes. For this situation there are certainly indirect approaches like:

- packing all the relavent codes into a single function;
- integrating the relavent codes into a package or a notebook
- etc...

---

### update 2: more background

The number of global variables and main functions of the notebook is ~100. The simplest function (three-point in 1-dim) is like the followings. As you can see, tracking all symbols across functions is inconvenient.

The current method I used is saving all the codes into one notebook `init1.nb`, and working in another notebook with

```
Module[{path,notebook},path=NotebookDirectory[]<>"init1.nb";
notebook=NotebookOpen[path,CellContext->"Global`"];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[notebook,"SelectAll"]];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[notebook,"Evaluate"]]
]
```

**Example codes:**

```
threePoint[x1_, x2_, 
   x3_, \[CapitalDelta]1_, \[CapitalDelta]2_, \[CapitalDelta]3_] := \
(x1 - x2)^(-\[CapitalDelta]1 - \[CapitalDelta]2 + \[CapitalDelta]3) \
(x2 - x3)^(\[CapitalDelta]1 - \[CapitalDelta]2 - \[CapitalDelta]3) \
(-x1 + x3)^(-\[CapitalDelta]1 + \[CapitalDelta]2 - \[CapitalDelta]3) \
;
threePointCoefficient[rank1_, rank2_, rank3_, i1_, i2_, i3_] := 
  0 /; (i1 <= 0 || i1 > rank1) || (i2 <= 0 || 
      i2 > rank2) || (i3 <= 0 || i3 > rank3);
threePointCoefficient[rank1_, rank2_, rank3_, i1_, i2_, i3_] := 
  sub[symbolThreePointCoefficient, i1, i2, i3];
threePointFactor[{rank1_, rank2_, rank3_, i1_, i2_, i3_}, k1_, k2_, 
   k3_] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n1 = 0\), \(rank1 - i1\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n2 = 0\), \(rank2 - i2\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n3 = 0\), \(rank3 - i3\)]
\*FractionBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(k1\), \(n1\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(k2\), \(n2\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(k3\), \(n3\)]\), \(\(n1!\)\ \(n2!\)\ \(n3!\)\)]\ \
threePointCoefficient[rank1, rank2, rank3, i1 + n1, i2 + n2, 
       i3 + n3]\)\)\);
threePointFactor2[{rank1_, rank2_, rank3_, i1_, i2_, i3_}, x1_, x2_, 
   x3_] := 
  threePointFactor[{rank1, rank2, rank3, i1, i2, 
    i3}, -Log@ratioX[x2, x3, x1], -Log@ratioX[x3, x1, x2], -Log@
     ratioX[x1, x2, x3]];
threePoint[{rank1_, rank2_, rank3_, i1_, i2_, i3_}, x1_, x2_, 
   x3_, \[CapitalDelta]1_, \[CapitalDelta]2_, \[CapitalDelta]3_] := 
  threePoint[x1, x2, 
    x3, \[CapitalDelta]1, \[CapitalDelta]2, \[CapitalDelta]3] \
threePointFactor[{rank1, rank2, rank3, i1, i2, 
     i3}, -Log@ratioX[x2, x3, x1], -Log@ratioX[x3, x1, x2], -Log@
      ratioX[x1, x2, x3]];
```

[image]

Comment: You could try CellPrint.

Comment: Are you trying to get some sort of history? Does it need to span sessions? Could you just use some aggregation structure instead of relying on display?

Comment: @lericr I'm sorry that I don't know the things you mentioned. I want the following behaviour: each time running `foo[]` will generate a new cell storing the messages, prints and outputs, instead of overwritting the latest ones.

Comment: @lericr so that I can comparing the results against different `$globalvariable[]` conveniently.

Comment: Use a `Table`, e.g., `Table[{var, f[var]}, {var, {val1, val2, val3}}] // Grid` or if the variable values fit a pattern use a standard iterator (`{var, start, end, step}`) in the `Table`

Comment: This recent Q&A might be of interest to you: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271105/ - it is about how to take a notebook (such as yours) and conveniently run it for many inputs

Comment: @LukasLang Thx! That is quite similar to my question. I'll try finding some solution suitable for mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @lericr, I tried the functions related to `CellPrint` and read `tutorial/ManipulatingNotebooks`. With some efforts I'm satisfied with the following codes:

```
rerun//Attributes={HoldAllComplete};
rerunCounter[___]:=0;
rerunCollector[___]:={};
rerunCache[]={};

rerun[codes___][collector_String]:=
Block[{Print},Module[{celllsit,counter},
    (*set the counter wrt. collector*)
    rerunCounter[collector]++;
    counter=rerunCounter[collector];
    rerunCollector[]=joinUnique[rerunCollector[],{collector}];
    rerunCollector[collector]=Join[rerunCollector[collector],{counter}];
    (*preprint messages*)
    celllsit["preprint"]={
        ExpressionCell[
            StringTemplate["Current run: `` at ``"][counter,collector],
            "Output",
            ShowCellTags->True,
            ShowCellLabel->True
        ],
        ExpressionCell[
            DateString[{"ISODate"}],            "Output",
            rerunCellOptions["Date",counter]
        ]
    };
    (*store the Print messages by cells*)
    celllsit["print"]={};
    Print[exprs___]:=rerunFunPrint[celllsit["print"],exprs];
    (*evaluation of codes*)
    rerunCache[collector,counter]={codes};
    (* the results*)
    celllsit["eval"]=Table[
        ExpressionCell[
            coderesult,
            "Output",
            rerunCellOptions["Run",counter]
        ],
        {coderesult,rerunCache[collector,counter]}
    ];
    celllsit["total"]=Join[celllsit["preprint"],celllsit["print"],celllsit["eval"]];
    CellPrint@celllsit["total"];
]];

rerunFunPrint//Attributes={HoldFirst};
rerunFunPrint[celllist_,exprs__]:=
    AppendTo[celllist,
        ExpressionCell[
            Row[{exprs}],
            "Print",
            CellAutoOverwrite->False
        ]
    ];
rerunCellOptions[label_String,counter_Integer]:=
    {
        CellAutoOverwrite->False,
        CellLabel->StringTemplate["``[``]= "][label,counter],
        CellLabelAutoDelete->False,
        ShowCellTags->True,
        ShowCellLabel->True
    };
rerunCacheClear[collector_String]:=
    (
        Table[
            rerunCache[collector,$$counter]=.,
        {$$counter,rerunCounter[collector]}
        ];
        rerunCounter[collector]=.;
        rerunCollector[collector]=.;
        rerunCollector[]=complement[rerunCollector[],{collector}];
    )
rerunCacheClear[]:=
    (
        rerunCacheClear/@rerunCollector[];
    )
```

For the following test function, the results are,

```
a=1;
f[___]:=(Print@a;Print[x,y];a++;a)
```

[image]
Using `rerunCacheClear` can clear the stored results:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

> so that I can comparing the results against different $globalvariable[] conveniently

Rather than answer your initial question directly, I'm going to try to address this objective from your comment. And I apologize for getting philosophical. People often "just want the answer to my question", but they can't see that there are better possibilities around the corner if they would just shift their perspective a bit.

Don't use global data. Or at least, don't use it this way. Let's make a better `foo` to illustrate:

```
foo[] := Print@$globalvariable[] (*bad form, subtle dependencies, difficult to test*)
betterFoo[arg_] := Print[arg] (*better form, no magic, but no output that we can get our hands on (Print is a side-effect)*)
bestFoo[arg_] := arg (*we now have an actual thing that we can store, manipulate, compose, etc.*)
```

Now, `bestFoo` looks ridiculous because it does nothing to its argument, but I'm assuming this was just an example, so let's say it's something more interesting like:

```
bestFoo[arg_] := {arg^2, Sin[arg], 17/arg}
```

At this point, let's say you still have your `$globalvariable[]` function. Instead of `foo[]` you'd use `bestFoo[$globalvariable[]]`. But you can also do `bestFoo[5]`. That is, you're now no longer dependent on your global data--you could compare `bestFoo[5]` with `bestFoo[10]` immediately and directly without figuring out how to update your global data.

Now, let's say you want to "conveniently compare the result using different data" (paraphrased). Let's say the data you want to apply `foo`/`bestFoo` to are `{1,10,100}`:

```
AssociationMap[bestFoo, {1, 10, 100}]
(* 
this gives:
<|1 -> {1, Sin[1], 17}, 10 -> {100, Sin[10], 17/10}, 100 -> {10000, Sin[100], 17/100}|>
*)
```

Now you have a structure holding the results of your various "runs". You don't need to rely on the front end display to see your history. You could save this to a file. You can keep adding to it over time. You can do more computational comparative analyses across different runs.

The objection here is most likely going to be "but the global data is complicated, the `foo` is complicated, this answer works for these simplisitic examples, but that's not what my real data looks like". Feel free to add more detail to what your data looks like, what `foo` really does, what your context is, and what your actual objective is, and we can help you find a path to what will work for you.

Comment: Thx! I have add more descriptions in the question.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand your update.

Comment: Specifically, I don't know what you expect from a "pre-package", I don't know what the "outputs" are that you use to adjust your "global settings" and "main functions", and I don't know why those outputs need to be displayed without overwriting. I'm thinking that you just have a workflow that I'm entirely unfamilar with, but you're assuming that it's so obvious that it doesn't need to be described.

Comment: It all sounds very confusing and disorganized to me. I'll go back to "don't use global data", because I suspect that that is the root of your difficulties.

Comment: sorry that I cannot provide the complete codes here. Tracking all the relavent symbol dependencies across the functions seems impossible for me, since there are roughly tens of local variables and global ones sending from one function into another, and there are roughly one hundred functions in one notebook. It's impossible to recontruct them :<

Comment: The simplest example is a six-point function in four-dimension, there are 6x4 local variables as the six points, and tens of global ones labeling the operators.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that there would be complexity. I don't need the details of your data or your functions. I'm trying to understand what you're objective actually is. You started with wanting evaluations to not overwrite previous outputs, but it sounds like what you really want is an efficient process for developing packages. That's a completely different objective that in all likelihood will not require what you originally asked for.

Comment: And now I see that you're using `FrontEndExecute` to evaluate the contents of a notebook. This all just seems very indirect and awkward. Why don't you just use `Get` or proper packages?

Comment: `As you can see, tracking all symbols across functions is inconvenient.` No, I don't see that at all. If you have 100 parameters, then you have 100 parameters. Making them global variables doesn't magically reduce the complexity. Maybe my comments have just de-railed this whole thing. Sorry to have added to the confusion.

Comment: In the earlier attemps several months ago, I tried integrating them into a package. But sadly some functions depend on the `Context` and without careful reconstruction, they cannot be moved into package simply. As you noticed, these issues are away from the original request of this question. This question is about how to preserve the old outputs, which I'm not familiar with. No problem, any comment is welcomed, since I can learn more things from the discussion.

Comment: My only suggestion is to preserve the outputs as actual data, rather than relying on the notebook display mechanisms.

Comment: Using `CellPrint` I wrote an answer that partially solve this problem. Do you know how to add `CellLabels` properly when `CellPrint`? I also tried `NotebookWrite`, but `NotebookWrite` doesn't accept `ExpressionCell`.

Comment: CellLabel and CellTags are just options for Cell (and anything that evaluates to Cell, like TextCell). You may also need the related Show* options. For example: `CellPrint[TextCell["hello", CellLabel -> "wonder woman", CellTags -> {"superman"}, ShowCellTags -> True, ShowCellLabel -> True]]`.

Comment: Many thx! `ShowCellLabel ` is exactly what I missed.